# getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS crash when I try to assign datasource to a property in a custom UIView

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, uitableview

I am trying to assign the `datasource` to a `datasource` property of a custom `UIView` which has a `UITableView` `subView`. The code is as followed:

**`CustomUIView.m`**

```
- (void)setDataSource:(id<UITableViewDataSource>)dataSource
{
    self.dataSource = dataSource;
    if (!self.tableView) {
        [self createTableView];
        [self setUpTableViewSizeAndAddToSuperView];
    }

    self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
}
```

**`CustomUIView.h`**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
```

The datasource is provided in a property called delegateobject in a  UIViewController.

**`UIViewController.m`**

```
self.customView.dataSource = delegateobject;
```

**`UIViewController.h`**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) DelegateObject *delegateobject;
```

DelegateObject is just a `NSObject` with `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

But when I ran the app it gave me the `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error and crashed. 
The `datasource` property of my custom `UIView` has been released too many times and stopped at this line:

```
self.dataSource = dataSource;
```

I have enabled zombie objects diagnosis but couldn't see any additional information. How can I fix this?

Comment: This won't solve your problems but don't set the delegates properties as `strong`, make them `weak/assign`. If you use `strong` you will end up into a retain cycle therefore memory leak.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to solve my problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `self.dataSource = dataSource`, you are creating an infinite loop. When you override a setter you need to set the instance variable directly, so change that line to:

```
_dataSource = dataSource;
```

Comment: OK I get it. I put @synthesize dataSource = _dataSource in CustomUIView.m. I think this solves my problem very well.

Comment: you shouldnt need to put that synthesize unless you are using an old version of Xcode